# Xamarin.Forms Refresh ContentPage in TabbedPage

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I'm new to app development and I created an app with a TabbedPage as MainPage. This TabbedPage has 3 children (ContentPages).
Now when I'm switching between the tabs, the tabbed page doesn't refresh. 
For example in one ContentPage it's possible to enter some data, and the other ContentPage should show these data now. 
So my question is how can I refresh (new instance or something like this) the ContentPage when I click on it's tab.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide some code you've written so people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case I would have one view model that is assigned as the binding context of the tabbed page, and then it should just work.

If you are not into using view models, which is recommended, you may try with messaging center https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center to communicate among the pages.

Finally you can always use some sort of events to communicate among classes, just in this case it really wouldn't be recommended to do that.